# Run generated scripts against tablespaces_Oracle

Tags: oracle

The homework asks to re-org a fragmented tablespace. Instead of manually copy and drop each table between two tablespaces, the homework requires to write a script that will generate a script file which automatically runs against the tablespace and reconstruct it.

How to generate a script that runs automatically against thousands of tables?

Comment: Its good task to learn.   you can note down what all manula step need to  do . Same way try to generate script those SQL statements.  Move the tables another data files and shrink  original data file .

Comment: I think homework involves making some challenges to get knowledge about given problem area. If someone gives you an answer how to do it, it won't give anything. So go ahead , achieve some results yourself and if get some problems during your challenge we will try to solve them with pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

you can use following query :
select 'alter table '||table_name ||' move tablespace NewTableSpace ' from dba_tables where TABLESPACE_NAME='current tablespace name';

if your table's owner is special user then use where clouse :
where owner = 'the owner name'
if you
remember that :first you need to create new tablespace with name :NewTableSpace
be carefull about the space of new tablespace(your new tablespace have to had enough space.

Comment: how do I quote ' when i need to create a datafile?   select 'create tablespace MyTS datafile',substr(file_name,1,8),'-3.DBF SIZE 12M'
from DBA_DATA_FILES 
where upper(tablespace_name) = 'MYTS'; this query doesn't have ' around datafile name.

Comment: for move tables to new tablespace you dont need to create new datafile but it is necessary to have space in new tablespace.
I mean ,just one datafile in tablespace is enough(with autoextend property)

but if you you want to create datafile with unique name you can use following query :
select  'create tablespace MyTS datafile '||SUBSTR(file_name,1,LENGTH(file_name)-4)||TO_CHAR((SELECT MAX(FILE_ID) FROM DBA_DATA_FILES)+ROWNUM)||'.DBF SIZE 12M' from DBA_DATA_FILES where upper(tablespace_name) = 'PSAPSR3';